# How to add a quote in front of "https" using Python and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a Python script that is importing links from one CSV file formatting it and then sending it to a different CSV file. I am running into a problem in the formatting phase.

I want to add a `"` before the `https` in the link. Below is the Python code I am using.

```
df['Link'] = df['Link'].apply(lambda x: "\"href:\\{0}\\""\"\"".format(x))

## We just need to get a quote infront of the https
df['Link'][0]
df #

link_list = df['Link']
link_list_grab = link_list[0:50]
```

Above script is returning below which is not correct

```
"href:\https://www.lifenews.com""
```

I want it to return as below

```
"href:\"https://www.lifenews.com""
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this line...

`df['Link'] = df['Link'].apply(lambda x: "\"href:\\{0}\\""\"\"".format(x))`

Try this...

`df['Link'] = df['Link'].apply(lambda x: '\"href:\\"{0}\\""\"\"'.format(x))`

Comment: It would be helpful to add an explanation